# How much load can cassandra handle on m1.xlarge instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, garbage-collection, cassandra

I setup 3 nodes of Cassandra (1.2.10) cluster on 3 instances of EC2 m1.xlarge.

Based on default configuration with several guidelines included, like:

- datastax_clustering_ami_2.4
- not using EBS, raided 0 xfs on ephemerals instead,
- commit logs on separate disk,
- RF=3,
- 6GB heap, 200MB new size (also tested with greater new size/heap values),
- enhanced limits.conf.

With **500 writes per second**, the cluster works only for couple of hours. After that time it seems like not being able to respond because of CPU overload (mainly GC + compactions).

Nodes remain Up, but their load is huge and logs are full of GC infos and messages like:

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests:186] 2013-12-10 18:38:12,412 ErrorMessage.java (line 210) Unexpected exception during request java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

nodetool shows many dropped mutations on each node:

```
Message type           Dropped
RANGE_SLICE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  7
BINARY                       0
READ                         2
MUTATION               4072827
_TRACE                       0
REQUEST_RESPONSE          1769
```

Is 500 wps too much for 3-node cluster of m1.xlarge and I should add nodes? Or is it possible to further tune GC somehow? **What load are you able to serve with 3 nodes of m1.xlarge? What are your GC configs?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cassandra is perfectly able to handle *tens of thousands* small writes per second on a single node. I just checked on my *laptop* and got about 29000 writes/second from cassandra-stress on Cassandra 1.2. So 500 writes per second is not really an impressive number even for a single node.

However beware that there is also a limit on how fast data can be flushed to disk and you definitely don't want your incoming data rate to be close to the physical capabilities of your HDDs. Therefore 500 writes per second can be too much, if those writes are big enough.

So first - what is the average size of the write? What is your replication factor? Multiply number of writes by replication factor and by average write size - then you'll approximately know what is required write throughput of a cluster. But you should take some safety margin for other I/O related tasks like compaction. There are various benchmarks on the Internet telling a single m1.xlarge instance should be able to write anywhere between 20 MB/s to 100 MB/s...

If your cluster has sufficient I/O throughput (e.g. 3x more than needed), yet you observe OOM problems, you should try to:

1. reduce memtable_total_space_mb (this will cause C* to flush smaller memtables, more often, freeing heap earlier)
2. lower write_request_timeout to e.g. 2 seconds instead of 10 (if you have big writes, you don't want to keep too many of them in the incoming queues, which reside on the heap)
3. turn off row_cache (if you ever enabled it)
4. lower size of the key_cache
5. consider upgrading to Cassandra 2.0, which moved quite a lot of things off-heap (e.g. bloom filters and index-summaries); this is especially important if you just store lots of data per node
6. add more HDDs and set multiple data directories, to improve flush performance
7. set larger new generation size; I usually set it to about 800M for a 6 GB heap, to avoid pressure on the tenured gen.
8. if you're sure memtable flushing lags behind, make sure sstable compression is enabled - this will reduce amount of data physically saved to disk, at the cost of additional CPU cycles

Comment: Well for the rate of our I/O, performance was awful (even with ephemeral storage), so we ended up ditching it. I don't think we were pulling a lot of data into it as we were reading/writing data from S3 and dumping it into C* (Although it was realtime). There could have been a parameter that could have improved our performance but in the end we decided not to waste our time. Don't get me wrong, it may work in a lot cases and some people are big fans, but it didn't work us. It's our strictly subjective opinion.

Comment: I further investigated the cluster. I run number of stress tests on it (including the one attached to datastax java drivers) and it looks like the cluster itself is able to manage about 5K writes per second during the tests. It also behaves stable. Now I think that the problem is in the specific data structure that we have, or maybe driver usage? Is it possible that composite keys have such a performance penalty? What else may matter?

Comment: @Rico which version was it? Maybe you were hit by some bug? E.g. just recently I stress-tested an early C* 2.0 version and got awful performance, then realized I'm not on the latest stable version - upgraded and it worked like charm.

Comment: @Bartek What is the average size of the write? Are you using prepared statements? What is your load-balancing strategy? Is your cluster well balanced and are your writes well distributed? Are there any warnings/errors in the system.log?

Comment: @PiotrKolaczkowski average write is about 4K. It has composite key built of UUID and timestamp. We're using prepared statements. We use vnodes with 256 tokens set per node. The cluster is well balanced and writes are distributed evenly. No errors/warnings in system.log until the situation is really bad. Then lots of GC traces and finally:  ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests:100] 2013-12-12 13:36:40,903 ErrorMessage.java (line 210) Unexpected exception during request
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe (...)

Comment: We were using "Datastax 1.1 Community Server". I think the version could have been the culprit of our performance problems.

Comment: Can you attach GC logs to the question? Have you tried considerably upping HEAP_NEWSIZE in cassandra-env.sh? Have you tried significantly lowering memtable size?

Comment: It's pretty safe to say you shouldn't be starting with 1.1 today.  I'd suggest 1.2.latest and be sure to take Piotr's advice about lowering write_request_timeout (2s is the new default in 2.0).

Comment: @jbellis he started with 1.2

Comment: Then I stand by my recommendation to change wrt. :)